# flutter_bloc BlocBuilder not rebuilding as well state change not observed in BlocObserver

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

i am new to flutter , trying to implement counter app using flutter_bloc.
widget withBlocBuilder is not rebuilding even after emitting state.
added BlocObserver and found only once state change happened .
could someone help ?
below is the git repo :
https://github.com/gopiKrishnaPuligundla/japa_counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was you were incrementing both the old state and the new state in `increment()` of your `CounterBloc`.

```dart
void increment(IncrementCounter event, Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
  print("increment");
  // ------------ Here you are updating the old State ---------------
  state.counter.incrementCount();
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  emit(
    CounterState(
      counter: Counter(
        liveCount:state.counter.liveCount,
        liveRounds: state.counter.liveRounds,
      )
    )
  );
}
```

So by the time, the `CounterBloc` compare the new state with the old one which you defined by the `Equatable`, it will appear the same.

```dart
@override
List<Object?> get props => [
  _liveRounds,
  _liveCount
];

// Old State
// [0, 2]

// New State
// [0, 2]

// They are considered the same, so BlocBuilder will not be updated
```

How to fix it? Well, you can just create new `CounterState` with the updated value and not via updating the old one.

```dart
void increment(IncrementCounter event, Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
  print("increment");
  // -------------- Do not update the old state ----------------------
  // state.counter.incrementCount();
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  emit(
    CounterState(
      counter: Counter(
        // ------------------- Increment on New State-----------------
        liveCount:state.counter.liveCount + 1,
        // -----------------------------------------------------------
        liveRounds: state.counter.liveRounds,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

For `decrement()`,

```dart
void decrement(DecrementCounter event, Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
  print("decrement");
  // state.counter.decrementCount();
  emit(
    CounterState(
      counter: Counter(
        liveCount:state.counter.liveCount - 1,
        liveRounds: state.counter.liveRounds,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: My pleasure and good luck!